# Mixed Gateway HTTP-WEBSOCKET in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

In your opinion, in a hybrid architecture (WEBSOCKET + HTTP) is it good practice to use 2 gateways: Zuul for HTTP communication and Spring Cloud Gateway for WEBSOCKET communication in a Spring Boot application? Alternatively, in this scenario is it recommended to use only Spring Cloud Gateway?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

**is it recommended to use only Spring Cloud Gateway** *Yes* because

[Spring Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529203/6332074) does not provide any out of the box integration with Zuul2. Gateway has many features that are not available in the public version of Zuul2 such as Rate limiting, etc. Also, with the gateway you can have custom filters defined per route and there are tons of built-in filters defined as well, which helps a lot to get started. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537489/6332074)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529538/6332074): I think SCG is the way to go due to the agreements between Netflix and Pivotal, with the former leaning more toward the spring boot/cloud ecosystem as stated in https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/netflix-oss-and-spring-boot-coming-full-circle-4855947713a0

Comment: Did you find any better idea?